# My CSS and HTML/Javascript is not working on some of my pages

Tags: jquery, slider, fullscreen

I am trying to use this [jQuery script for full-screen sliders](http://codecanyon.net/item/fss-full-screen-sliding-website-plugin/159103) and for some reason, it doesn't seem to be working! The overall plugin works, but the HTML on the individual pages isn't working for some reason. What's wrong?

Here is my `index.html`: http://goatsy.me/motoring

And here is my `about.html` and `contact.html`.
(Which work when viewed individually, but not when viewed in index.html)
http://goatsy.me/motoring/links/about.html

The weirdest part (to me) is that my `maindex.html` *is* working when viewed separately, and also when viewed within `index.html`.

Comment: Must admit that my heart skipped a beat visiting a site whose name is ever so similar to the dreaded goatse.

Comment: What do you expect to see, and what is actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that you aren't loading the css that you use on the other pages (about etc)

If you include the css on your index all should be well:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/motoring/links/expandable-box-demo/style.css">
```

A good way to catch this sort of thing is to use a debugging tool ( [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) if you are using firefox, or the chrome developer tools) - A quick look at the console reveals several requests which don't find their file.

Comment: Thank you very much! I haven't done coding for a few years now, so I need some memory-refreshing! Thanks for that firebug recommendation, I'll definitely try it out! I went back and changed a bunch of stuff in the code and now I screwed the whole thing up and now the bubble navigation jquery isn't even working! GREEEEAAAT :D lol.

Comment: oh and, btw.. u should check out mylittlegoatsy.com don't worry it's not pr0n! (unfortunately) 8]